# custom jquery alert closes automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a web page which I am developing with Visual Basic under .net 4.0.  I have a simple page with some buttons.  When I click on a specific button, I execute a javascript function which makes use of jalert().  The alert appears correctly, but then closes by itself without me having to click the OK button on the displayed dialog.

This is the code of my page:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="test.aspx.vb" Inherits="AccuRecordDirect.test1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title id="titleTag">
</title>    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link href="~/bootstrap/content/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />       
<script src="~/bootstrap/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../bootstrap/scripts/js/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="../../bootstrap/scripts/js/jquery/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="../../bootstrap/scripts/js/jquery/jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../bootstrap/scripts/js/jquery/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script src="~/bootstrap/Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="~/Styles/Site_vsta.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="~/bootstrap/content/Site_vsta.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

<style type="text/css">
@media (min-width:992px) {
.mobile-only {display:none;}
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
.desktop-only {display:none;} 
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="container body-content">
        <div class="row">            
            <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="panel panel-default mobile-only" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
                    <div class="panel-heading"">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Online Enrollment - Investment Elections" CssClass="panel-title mobile-only"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Select how you want to set up your investment elections and click the <B><I>Next</I></B> button below." CssClass="control-label mobile-only"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="&nbsp;" CssClass="control-label mobile-only"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel_M" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm mobile-only" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btn_Target_M" runat="server" Text="Target" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm mobile-only" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btn_Risk_M" runat="server" Text="Risk" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm mobile-only" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btn_Select_M" runat="server" Text="Select" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm mobile-only" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function showPopup_M() {
        jAlert('We encourage you to take the investment risk', 'Risk Category Selected');
    }    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my codebehind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then
        Me.btn_Risk_M.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:showPopup_M();")
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is performing a form post (PostBack). This is the normal behavior. A PostBack will refresh the page so any client side actions done with javascript will be lost.

Change your button attribute to

```
btn_Risk_M.Attributes.Add("onclick", "showPopup_M(); return false;")
```

Or if you are not using any asp.net functions of that button (OnClick, Visibility etc), you could change it into a non aspnet one.

```
<input type="button" onclick="showPopup_M()" value="Risk" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mobile-only" />
```